# Cannot access default CustomStringConvertible `description` variable value within codable struct

Tags: ios, swift, macos

This is a strange one due to requirements of the project. Essentially I have struct conforming to `Codable` and `CustomStringConvertible` which I am using to decode JSON, however I am required to use the default implementation of description which I can't seem to do as description does not have a matching CodingKey and does not have a default value. Is there any way I can access the default value for description without using my own custom string? Example below

```
struct Source: CustomStringConvertible {
    
    var description: String

    var symbol: String
    var line: Int
    var image: String
    var file: String
}

extension Source: Codable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case symbol
        case line
        case image
        case file
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should never use `description` for anything other than debug logging. It should be considered a "reserved property". Use `CodingKeys` to map to some other property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to change your description property declaration and make it a computed property instead:

```
var description: String { "Source - Symbol: \(symbol), Line: \(line), Image: \(image), File: \(file), " }
```

Note that there is no need to explicitly declare the coding keys:

```
struct Source: Codable { 
    let symbol, image, file: String
    let line: Int
}
```

---

```
extension Source: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "Source - Symbol: \(symbol), Line: \(line), Image: \(image), File: \(file), " }
}
```